# Complex nested URLs in Flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am building a panel with Flask admin.

I have a class User, which is displayed and edited on `/admin/user`

And a class Asset, which can be displayed on `/admin/asset`

I want to create a URL `/admin/user/{id}/asset`, that will be the same view as `/admin/asset` (with auto-generated pages to edit and delete), but filtered by the user ID.

Is it possible to implement such routing with Flask admin?